# Seemingly wrong instruction pointer reported by VS2017

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, x86-64, visual-studio-debugging, disassembly

### Edit:

I've investigated more, and the problem reported below seems to happen only when I use Visual Studio 2017 to pause the process. It also seems that when rip is pointing to an invalid location, it's always a +1 byte offset from the correct instruction start.

Also, for context, this is a large C++ project with lots of dlls, some compiled with MSVC 2015, the rest with icc (intel compiler 2017). This is run in a python process using boost C++/python bindings.

### Original post:

I am pausing my program randomly to see what are my threads doing during some heavy computation.
Note that I am not debugging a crash, resuming the program works fine.

Howver the VS debugger is sometimes unable to dissassemble the machine code.
For instance, on one thread where rip=000007FE8B048EE2, it shows this:

```
000007FE8B048EDE  ?? ?? 
000007FE8B048EDF  ?? ?? 
000007FE8B048EE0  ?? ?? 
000007FE8B048EE1  ?? ?? 
                    }

                    if (params.derandomize) {
000007FE8B048EE2  adc         ebp,eax  
                        GetRNG().Seed(id);
000007FE8B048EE4  pop         rax  
000007FE8B048EE5  wait  
000007FE8B048EE6  adc         byte ptr [rax],al  
000007FE8B048EE8  mov         rcx,rax
```

The decoded x86 instructions also seem wrong (adc, pop, wait, adc ??), so I tried to attach WinDBG as well (non invasive mode):

```
0:019> u rip
somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x132:
000007fe`8b048ee2 13e8            adc     ebp,eax
000007fe`8b048ee4 58              pop     rax
000007fe`8b048ee5 9b              wait
000007fe`8b048ee6 1000            adc     byte ptr [rax],al
000007fe`8b048ee8 4889c1          mov     rcx,rax
000007fe`8b048eeb 8b9570080000    mov     edx,dword ptr [rbp+870h]
000007fe`8b048ef1 e8fa911000      call    somedll!bla::bla::blabla::blabla::Seed (000007fe`8b1520f0)
000007fe`8b048ef6 4c8ba5b0080000  mov     r12,qword ptr [rbp+8B0h]
```

Ok, it's the same garbage...
But then I tried to dissassemble from an address slightly above rip:

```
0:019> u rip-30
somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x102:
000007fe`8b048eb2 00488b          add     byte ptr [rax-75h],cl
000007fe`8b048eb5 084863          or      byte ptr [rax+63h],cl
000007fe`8b048eb8 81d003000048    adc     eax,48000003h
000007fe`8b048ebe 83f8ff          cmp     eax,0FFFFFFFFh
000007fe`8b048ec1 740a            je      somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x11d (000007fe`8b048ecd)
000007fe`8b048ec3 4889c2          mov     rdx,rax
000007fe`8b048ec6 48899570080000  mov     qword ptr [rbp+870h],rdx
000007fe`8b048ecd 486381e0030000  movsxd  rax,dword ptr [rcx+3E0h]
0:019> u
somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x124:
000007fe`8b048ed4 483bd0          cmp     rdx,rax
000007fe`8b048ed7 7501            jne     somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x12a (000007fe`8b048eda)
000007fe`8b048ed9 cc              int     3
000007fe`8b048eda 80b96303000000  cmp     byte ptr [rcx+363h],0
000007fe`8b048ee1 7413            je      somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x146 (000007fe`8b048ef6)
000007fe`8b048ee3 e8589b1000      call    somedll!bla::bla::blabla::GetRNG (000007fe`8b152a40)
000007fe`8b048ee8 4889c1          mov     rcx,rax
000007fe`8b048eeb 8b9570080000    mov     edx,dword ptr [rbp+870h]
0:019> u
somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x141:
000007fe`8b048ef1 e8fa911000      call    somedll!bla::bla::blabla::blabla::Seed (000007fe`8b1520f0)
000007fe`8b048ef6 4c8ba5b0080000  mov     r12,qword ptr [rbp+8B0h]
000007fe`8b048efd 488d95f0070000  lea     rdx,[rbp+7F0h]
000007fe`8b048f04 488d8dc0070000  lea     rcx,[rbp+7C0h]
000007fe`8b048f0b 498b0424        mov     rax,qword ptr [r12]
000007fe`8b048f0f 4c8da570080000  lea     r12,[rbp+870h]
000007fe`8b048f16 488942d0        mov     qword ptr [rdx-30h],rax
000007fe`8b048f1a 4c8962d8        mov     qword ptr [rdx-28h],r12
```

the first instructions "add byte ptr" and "or byte ptr" at 000007fe`8b048eb2 don't make sense because rip-30 likely falls in the middle of an instruction, but after it seems to resync because it corresponds to the source code:

```
if (id == params.dbgbreak_id) {
    __debugbreak();
}

if (params.derandomize) {
    GetRNG().Seed(id);
}

000007fe`8b048ecd 486381e0030000  movsxd  rax,dword ptr [rcx+3E0h]
000007fe`8b048ed4 483bd0          cmp     rdx,rax                  // if (id == params.dbgbreak_id) {
000007fe`8b048ed7 7501            jne     somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x12a (000007fe`8b048eda)
000007fe`8b048ed9 cc              int     3                        // __debugbreak(); }
000007fe`8b048eda 80b96303000000  cmp     byte ptr [rcx+363h],0    // if (params.derandomize)
000007fe`8b048ee1 7413            je      somedll!<lambda239>::operator()+0x146 (000007fe`8b048ef6)
000007fe`8b048ee3 e8589b1000      call    somedll!bla::bla::blabla::GetRNG (000007fe`8b152a40)
000007fe`8b048ee8 4889c1          mov     rcx,rax
000007fe`8b048eeb 8b9570080000    mov     edx,dword ptr [rbp+870h]
000007fe`8b048ef1 e8fa911000      call    somedll!bla::bla::blabla::blabla::Seed (000007fe`8b1520f0)
```

clearly there is no instruction begining at 000007fe8b048ee2 !
There is je at 000007fe8b048ee1, and call at 000007fe8b048ee3

So... I thought, hmmm there's a bug in the debugger... let's check the registers:

```
0:019> r
rax=ffffffffffffffff rbx=000000000021d420 rcx=000000000021d5d0
rdx=0000000002696568 rsi=0000000000005d38 rdi=0000000056eefc40
rip=000007fe8b048ee2 rsp=0000000056eef5b0 rbp=0000000056eef5e0
 r8=0000000000000006  r9=000000000021d0b8 r10=0000000006456570
r11=0000000000000006 r12=0000000056eefe50 r13=00000000069a8820
r14=000000000021d1a8 r15=0000000056eefe60
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
```

What?? rip=000007fe8b048ee2 ?? How is that possible?

It explains why the debugger is showing garbage: it is trying to dissassemble starting from rip, but rip points to the middle of an instruction.
But why is the reported rip wrong? Is the OS culprit?
Am I missing something?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Version numbers? I'm not sure what do you mean, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Hi, what kind of the project? Could you share a simple sample which help reproduces the issue if possible.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Hi, this is a large C++ project with lots of dlls, some compiled with MSVC 2015, the rest with icc (intel compiler 2017). This is run in a python process using boost C++/python bindings. I'll try to reproduce this with a small project.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT It seems the issue only happen when I pause the process from VS2017, please see my edit.

Comment: Hi, I've checked your edit, but it's hard for me to configure create similar project to test if this issue is reproducible in this situation:( Does the same issue occurs in a small project?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Thanks for your interest. I'll try to reproduce it with a small project, and I'll let you know if I can.

Comment: Great! Any update feel free to contact me.